# Prolog Database Query

Tags: database, comparison, prolog

To make a dating database with facts in the form of:

`person(name, age, sex, height, weight, education, salary)`

Given the input of:

`datable(alex, X).`

`datable_weight_limit(alex, 170, X).` Where 170 is the threshold for weight

How can I return the names of potential matches with the rules:

1. Only opposite sexes can be matched
2. Males should be older than females
3. Males should have a higher education than females?

I have these relations set up:

```
edu_less(hs, bachelor).
edu_less(bachelor, master).
edu_less(master, phd).

edu_lesser(A, B):-
    edu_less(A, X),
    edu_lesser(X, B).
```

I've tried:

```
datable(X, Y):-

    person(X, Agel, Sexl, Heightl, Weightl, Educationl, Salaryl),

    person(Namem, Agem, Sexm, Heightm, Weightm, Educationm, Salarym),

    Sexm \== Sexl.

datable(X, Y):-

    person(X, Agel, Sexl, Heightl, Weightl, Educationl, Salaryl),

    Sexl == female,

    findall( X, person(X, _, male, _, _, _, _), Y).
```

But I seem to have no luck. Is there a function I'm missing or something I'm implementing wrong?

Comment: I think you are missing following case `edu_lesser(A, B) :- edu_less(A, B).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are almost correct. Try this:

```
datable(M, F):-
    person(M, AgeM, male, HeightM, WeightM, EducationM, SalaryM),
    person(F, AgeF, female, HeightF, WeightF, EducationF, SalaryF),
    AgeM >= AgeF,
    edu_lesser(EducationF, EducationM),
    datable_weight_limit(M, MaxWeight),
    MaxWeight >= WeightF.
```

Here we suppose, that education is also numbers. 
If you need also function - `datable(F,M)`:

```
datable(F,M) :-
     person(F, _, female, _, _, _, _),
     datable(M, F).
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I also have this relation set up:

edu_less(hs, bacherlor).
edu_less(bachelor, master).
edu_lesser(A, B):-
        edu_less(A, X),
        edu_lesser(X, B).

How can I make the datable function return males for females, instead of hardcoding it?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? You can delete second "reverse" function. And call datable(Male, Female). It should return all matching pairs.

Comment: I meant the input might not always be male, but I think you covered that with the reverse function. Sorry, I just learned Prolog yesterday.

Comment: If you have different input for sex, you can replace male/female in person with `SexM =/= SexF`, as you did.

Comment: Your code seems to see if two people are a match. How would you return the names of the people in the database that are a match? For example, if you input datable(alex, X). it would return X = betty, samantha, etc? Thanks

Comment: If you try: `datable(M,F)`, it should return pairs like `M = alex, F = betty`, `M = alex, F = samantha`, `M = john, F = betty`